# Invalid Use of Intertext in Aligned

Tags: align, intertext

I've been using `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` for a while, but for posting homework solutions in enumerated environments I've started using `$\begin{aligned}[t] ... \end{aligned}$` instead. However I've just noticed that `\intertext{...}` doesn't work in `aligned`. Can someone offer a solution or workaround? (I would ideally like to continue with `aligned`.

MWE:

```
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    \text{\#Cars}
    &= \int_0^{20} \left[600 + 300\sin\left(4\sqrt{x+.15}\right)\right] \,dx\\
    &= \int_0^{20} 600 \,dx + 300 \int_0^{20} \sin\left(4\sqrt{x+.15}\right) \,dx\\
%   \intertext{For the latter integral, let $w = \sqrt{x+.15}$; thus $w^2 = x+.15$ and $dx = 2w \,dw$. So}
    &= 12,000 + 600 \int_{w^2 = .15}^{w^2 = 20.15} w \sin(4w) \,dw\\
%   \intertext{Using the Table of Integrals III-15}
    &= \left. 12,000 - 150 w \cos(4w) + 37.5 \sin(4w) \right\rvert_{w=\sqrt{.15}}^{w=\sqrt{20.15}}\\
    &\approx 12,000 - 487 = 11,513~\text{cars}
\end{aligned}$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a suitable replacement for `\intertext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\alignedintertext}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \vskip\belowdisplayshortskip
    \vtop{\hsize=\linewidth#1\par
    \expandafter}%
    \expandafter\prevdepth\the\prevdepth
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
    \text{\#Cars}
    &= \int_0^{20} [600 + 300\sin(4\sqrt{x+0.15})] \,dx\\
    &= \int_0^{20} 600 \,dx + 300 \int_0^{20} \sin(4\sqrt{x+0.15}) \,dx\\
    \alignedintertext{For the latter integral, let $w = \sqrt{x+0.15}$;
       thus $w^2 = x+0.15$ and $dx = 2w \,dw$. So}
    &= 12{,}000 + 600 \int_{w^2 = 0.15}^{w^2 = 20.15} w \sin(4w) \,dw\\
    \alignedintertext{Using the Table of Integrals III-15}
    &= 12{,}000 - 150 w \cos(4w) + 37.5 \sin(4w) 
          \big\rvert_{w=\sqrt{0.15}}^{w=\sqrt{20.15}}\\
    &\approx 12{,}000 - 487 = 11{,}513~\text{cars}
\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I've made a few corrections. First, I removed the useless (and harmful) `\left` and `\right` tokens; then I added a leading zero (`.15` is nearly unreadable and actually wrong) and braced the thousands comma separator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, @egreg. This is a very nice solution.

Comment: With your `\alignedintertext`, brackets are placed wrongly. Test with `\[\left\{\begin{aligned}\alignedintertext{abc}##123\end{aligned}\right\}\]` (where `##` indicates a newline for lack of newlines in comments).

Comment: @egreg Oh, then I am sorry for hijacking this thread. I thought `\intertext` gives you the ability to introduce a text line while forgetting about all alignment characters. Hence, I search for that feature with `aligned` and arrives at this answer.

Comment: @ComFreek This is to interrupt `aligned` inside a list environment, so the intertext lines agree with the context.  But everything is in `aligned`, so the `\left[` bracket is placed at the left of the whole construct. If you have a different need, please ask a new question with the details.